# Set default value in prop based on another prop

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Is it possible to set a default value of a prop based on what has been set as value for another prop?
For example, I want to be able to set a date format as one property, and a initial date if desired. The initial date should be displayed with the provided format. The props is defined like this:

```
  format:
  {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default:"DD.MM.YYYY"
  },
  init_date:
  {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: moment().format(this.format).toString()
  },
```

But this does not seem to work as moment seems to ignore `this.format` and use the default moment format instead. Hard coding it seems to work:

```
default: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString()
```

Is there anyway to get the value of `this.format` into the `init_date` property?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: your format string is in `this.format.default` not `this.format`, also, you can't set that inside of `data` `init_date` should be computed property.

Comment: @Deda: But will that work if a value actually has been set? Hence, that the default value should not be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to respond to changes in the `init_data` prop, use a computed value or a watch.

But the scenario i would use a shadow variable, you can use the props in the `data` function:

```
props: {
  init_date: { type: String, default: "" },
},
data() {
  let date_var = this.init_data;
  if (date_var === '') {
    date_var = moment().format(this.format).toString()
  }
  return {
    date_var 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You can't reference one prop in the default value of another. Instead of using a prop, you'll have to either use a `data` property and set the value in `mounted`, or use a `computed` property, or a method that takes the other prop as an input and returns a value (and then use whichever you choose in your template where you would use your prop).